# Dice Roller with Javascript Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, dice

I am working on creating a dice set with the functionalities of being able to set the number of sides on the dice as well as the amount of dice you want to roll. I am able to get console statements out, but not the right output on the page itself. Ideally, it would change the amount of dice sides and the amount of dice in the set after clicking the buttons. I also haven't been able to get my reset button to reset the statistics on screen. I believe I am running into issues when it comes to arrays, but I could be wrong. I am not looking for someone to do this for me; rather what I'm doing wrong and how I would go about fixing it

Here's [the application](http://studentweb.cdm.depaul.edu/~lsimon7/Assignment2/diceDemo.html) I've been using.

```js
numbers = [
  "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50"
]

$(function() {
  //var dice;
  // For creating a new Diceset
  dice = new DiceSet();


  $("#rollButton").click(function() {
    //var dice, outcomeList, message;
    outcomeList = dice.roll();
    console.log(outcomeList);


    // a good start, but you really don't want to reference //the array this way

    // use a for loop here instead of outcomeList

    message = "Rolled Dice!  " + outcomeList + " <br>";
    $("#outcome").append(message);






  });


  // place click handler for reset here
  $("#diceResetButton").click(function() {
    dice.reset();
    console.log("Reset is Supposed to happen...")



  });
  //click handler for changing the number of sides
  $("#setDiceSetSidesButton").click(function() {
    var select, chosen_number;
    dice.setNumSides(6);
    chosen_number = numbers[select];
    $("DiceSize").html(chosen_number);
    console.log("Amount of Sides on Dice Should Change...")
  });


  // click handler for setting the number of dice in the diceset 
  $("#setDiceSetSizeButton").click(function() {
    var select, chosen_number;
    dice.setDiceSetSize(2);
    chosen_number = numbers[select];
    $("DiceSides").html(chosen_number);
    console.log("Dice Set Amount Should change...")
  });



});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Dice Demo</title>
<script src=
  "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="dice.js"></script>
  <script src="diceLS.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Dice Roller Simulation</h1>
  
  
<input type="number" id="setDiceSetSize" value="2"
          id="DiceSize"> 

  <input type="button" id="setDiceSetSizeButton" value="Set Dice Size"/> 
  
  <br>
  
<input type="number" id="setDiceSetSides" value="6"
          id="DiceSides"> 

  <input type="button" id="setDiceSetSidesButton" value="Set Amount of Sides on Dice"/> 
  
  

  
<p> <input type="button" id="rollButton" value="Roll Dice"/> </p>  
  
  
  
  
  <p><input type="button" id="diceResetButton" value="Reset Dice Roll"/> </p>
  
<p id="outcome"> </p>
  
  
  
  

</body>
</html>
```

```js
//
// Example use:
//   dice = new DiceSet();
//
//   dice.roll() --> simulates roll and returns array of individual dice results
//   dice.numRolls() --> number of times the set of dice has been rolled
//   dice.getAverage() --> average totals from the sets
//   dice.history --> an array of totals from the set rolls
//
//   dice.reset() --> resets history of dice rolls
//
//   dice.setNumSides(8) --> configure for 8-sided DiceSet
//   dice.setDiceSetSize(4) --> roll 4 dice with each set


class DiceSet {
  constructor() {
    this.sides = 6;
    this.quantity = 2;
    this.history = [];
    this.runningTotal = 0;
  }

  singleRoll() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * this.sides + 1);
  }

  setNumSides(numSides) {
    this.sides = numSides;
    this.reset();
  }

  setDiceSetSize(numDice) {
    this.quantity = numDice;
    this.reset();
  }

  reset() {
    this.history = [];
    this.runningTotal = 0;
  }

  numRolls() {
    return this.history.length;
  }

  getAverage() {
    return this.runningTotal / this.history.length;
  }

  roll() {
    var total, same, rollSet, i;
    same = true;
    rollSet = [];
    rollSet[0] = this.singleRoll();
    total = rollSet[0];
    for (i = 1; i < this.quantity; i++) {
      rollSet[i] = this.singleRoll();
      total += rollSet[i];
      if (rollSet[i] !== rollSet[i-1]) {
        same = false;
      }
    }
    this.history.push(total);
    this.runningTotal += total;
    return rollSet;
    

  }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code in your question, not on a separate site - you can embed it with Stack Snippets so people can debug it live right here.

Comment: Thanks, I updated now @CertainPerformance

Comment: Which part you want to reset ?

Comment: @AlpeshJikadra I would like to reset the history of the outputs that appear on the page

Comment: After your reset button click event try **$("#outcome").html("");**

Comment: @AlpeshJikadra that worked, thank you so much!